# try to figure out why query rest api with PHP not work

Tags: php, rest, curl

i am still a php beginner and want to access a software via rest api and pass query parameters so i can transfer information from the software to my website. i have now spent hours trying to figure out how this is possible. here is my attempt...

provider's default:

```
curl https://api.software.com/v1/teams/xxx/databases/xxx/query?query=(select table).firstname
-X GET
-H "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxx"
-H "Content-Type": "application/json"
```

or

```
curl https://api.software.com/v1/teams/xxx/databases/xxx/query
-X POST
-H "Authorization": "Bearer xxxx"
-H "Content-Type": "application/json"
-D {
    "query": "(select table).firstname"
}
```

and this is my last try:

```
function callAPI2($method, $url, $data){

   $curl = curl_init();
   switch ($method){
      case "POST":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         break;
      case "PUT":
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
         if ($data)
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
         break;
      default:
         if ($data)
            $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
   }
   // OPTIONS:
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'Authorization: Bearer xxxx',

      'Content-Type: application/json',
   ));
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
   // EXECUTE:
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
   curl_close($curl);
   return $result;
};
 $options = array(
        'query' => '(select table).firstname',
    );
$make_call = callAPI2('GET', 'https://api.software.com/v1/teams/xxx/databases/xxx/query', $options); 
$test = json_decode($make_call,true);
var_dump($test);
echo $test;
?>
```

as response i get is nothing,..

after hours of trying i unfortunately have to give up and need help :-(

Comment: _"as response i get is nothing,.."_ - does not look as if you _actually_ verified that was the case. Got `null` from your var_dump there? All you did prove with that, is that the response was not valid JSON. Check what it contains, _before_ you try to decode it as the JSON it simply _might not be_, in case you got a plain text error message back.

Comment: change it to ```$test = json_decode($make_call,true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);``` and run it again :)

Comment: when I call var_dump($make_call), I get no response in the browser. Only a white-screen.

Comment: hey hanshenrik. same result. just an empty browser window

Comment: @robsn then you have display_errors=off in your php.ini - can you change your php.ini to `error_reporting=E_ALL display_errors=on` and run it again? this is the recommended settings for development. you are currently getting an error that you just can't see.

Comment: @hanshenrik the data are on a webspace at ionos and the website is wordpress. i'll try to change that, must inform me once how exactly i do that. have a private appointment right now and try it afterwards. thanks a lot!

Comment: @robsn well then there is a `php error log` somewhere, find the php error log. maybe ask customer support where to find the php error log.

Comment: It's need to see curl request is success or not . After that, you need to go forward. Better you should test api using postman client first